# How to trigger something within a resize event with a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to further my jQuery learning by making a tiny little basic plugin that will inject some HTML, apply CSS to that element (can be changed via passing options into the call) and finally displaying screen width and height on resize.

There are still elements such as the CSS that don't work for me yet. However one thing I don't know at the moment is how I can pass in an event listener for resize within my plugin?

My plugin so far:

```
$.fn.windowSize = function( options ) {
    // outline settings
    var settings = $.extend({
        color: "#000000",
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        position: "fixed",
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    }, options );

    // screen sizing vars
    var the_width = $(window).width();
    var the_height = $(window).height();  

    // measure html
    var measure = '<div id="measurements">' +
        '<span>Width:</span><span id="width">Risize to find out</span>' +
        '<span>Height:</span><span id="height">Risize to find out</span>' +
        '</div>';

    var measure_display = $("#measurements");

    // inject the measure elem to this
    this.prepend(measure);

    // use the default css
    return measure_display.css({
        color: settings.color,
        backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor,
        position: settings.position,
        top: settings.top,
        left: settings.left
    });

    // sets the html to display widths
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#width').text(the_width);
        $('#height').text(the_height);
    });
};
```

[Live, partially working example](http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/pxnfK).

***Update**

Essentially there is a part of my plugin where some values are triggered on window resize and rather than the user needing to write this outside of my plugin I want this within the plugin and so I am wanting to know if this is possible.

Comment: Do you mean recall a function every time a re size occurs?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @lugreen

Comment: $( window ).resize(function() {  someFunction(); }) // reload on resize.

Comment: But is there anyway to bundle this inside the plugin itself so the user doesnt need to do that? Or do you mean this can be placed within the plugin?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand you, but you can place that at the bottom of your plug-in and on any re-size event it will call what ever function/functions you place within in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function as a parameter to your `options` object, something like this:

```
$(window).resize(settings.resizeHandler);
```

Then you use it like this:

```
$('body').windowSize({
    resizeHandler: function () {
        console.log("window resize");
    }
});
```